# What is 'source=user_profile---------------------------' on URLs in Google results?

Tags: google-search

Just recently I've found my website showing in Google as

`www.example.com/?source=user_profile---------------------------`

I thought this might be something I'd inadvertently done in my code, but a search for the phrase shows lots of other URLs with the same.

Can anyone clue me in on what this is?

Comment: Here is a Google search result for it:   [https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&q=source+user_profile---------------------------](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&q=source+user_profile---------------------------)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done more research and it appears it's when there is an issue between the redirect of the http to https URL. I've fixed the issue and it no longer appears in Google results for my site.

Comment: What type of issue? What software and configuration was doing the redirects?

Comment: I had commented out my https redirect in .htaccess during testing and forgot to put it back in.